# Mypy - ignore syntax errors

Tags: mypy

I'm importing a module (namely tiktoken) into my code and mypy is finding that there is a syntax error (for those who are curious, on this line of code: [tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/blob/095924e02c85617df6889698d94515f91666c7ea/tiktoken/core.py#L116m))

```
invalid syntax  [syntax]
                if match := _special_token_regex(disallowed_special).searc...
```

I want to disable mypy for JUST the `import tiktoken`.

I've tried `# type: ignore`, but as the [mypy documentation says](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list.html#report-syntax-errors-syntax) , syntax errors are blocking errors and can't be ignored.

I don't want to put a # type: ignore at the top of my file either.

Is there a way I can do this, either through an inline comment or a mypy.ini file?

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date version of MyPy and have you told it what version of Python you're using?

Comment: It is not a syntax error for py3.9+. Are you sure that your python matches this requirement?

Comment: If mypy thinks that the walrus operator `:=` is a syntax error, and you haven't accidentally overridden the [`python_version` configuration](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-python_version), then you're using Python < 3.8, and `import tiktoken` will fail at runtime; mypy is the least of your concerns here.

Comment: I'm running mypy=1.3.0 and have python_version = 3.9 set in mypy.ini - I'm wondering if my mypy.ini isn't being properly understood, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[The walrus operator, `:=`, is new in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions). Running a script containing a walrus operator with any older version will result in a syntax error.